# Clearing the input field based on user confirmation in Rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

Hi I have an input for text and there is a clear button to clear the text. But before clearing I want to get a confirmation from user. So I have added a data confirm attribute as shown

```
<%= link_to 'Clear', '#', class: 'btn btn-danger btn-block', id: "status_clear", data: {confirm: 'Are you sure to clear the status?'} %>
```

In my coffeescript file

```
$('#status_clear').click (event)->
    event.preventDefault()
    $('#status_status').val('')
```

But the problem is both the actions are happening at once. I want the text field to be cleared only if the user confirms okay. I tried passing the data confirm attribute but it hasn't given whether the user clicked on okay or cancel. Please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `confirm` in the js code.

link:

```
<%= link_to 'Clear', '#', class: 'btn btn-danger btn-block', id: "status_clear" %>
```

js:

```
$('#status_clear').click (event)->
    event.preventDefault()
    if confirm('Are you sure to clear the status?') == true
      $('#status_status').val ''
    else
      # some code here
```